# GLSL frag shader - only works on nVidia, non-standard code?

Tags: opengl, glsl, sfml

EDIT: I'm sorry Stack Overflow, but I'm retarded. `frac(tex_offset)` -> `fract(tex_offset)`, and it works fine on ATI cards, and also nVidia cards when `#version` is specified now. This must be why most of the programmers I know don't have much hair left.

-

I'm working on a game for a school project. It's a vertical scroller, so one of the required features was a scrolling background. I tried a few approaches, but I eventually wrote a simple fragment shader (this is the first time I touch shader programming, so don't really know what I'm doing):

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform float tex_offset;

void main()
{
    vec2 coords = vec2(gl_TexCoord[0].s, gl_TexCoord[0].t - frac(tex_offset));
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, coords);
}
```

I use [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/) so I don't touch much of the stuff behind the scenes, but the texture I'm using is passed to the `tex` variable, and the `tex_offset` is generated in my game loop by taking the total elapsed seconds multiplied by a factor to control the scrolling speed.

This appears to do what it's supposed to; it indefinitely scrolls a seamless repeating texture in one direction. It works on my laptop, and it works on my home computer, which both have nVidia cards. However, when we tried to run it on a group member's computer with an ATI card, it simply did nothing. I did some googling and it seems like the nVidia cards accept "non-standard" GLSL code as well, which might explain the issues with compatibility. I find it difficult to find good tutorials/explanation on GLSL as most of the stuff I dig up is from version 1.2-1.4 and I'm apparently using syntax that was deprecated in version 3 (gl_FragColor, gl_TexCoord). However, when I tried to set `#version` to 120 or 140 or whatever, the shader also stopped working on my nVidia computers.

So, to try to phrase this into question form: what is wrong about this shader code? Is there any way to debug the syntax, and how do I turn on "standards" mode for my nVidia cards if this is possible?

Comment: maybe version 140 not supported

Comment: I don't think so @SAKrisT - I've systematically tried with version 110, 120, 130, 140, 150, 330, 400, 410 and 420. In fact, it only seems to work when I omit the `#version` tag entirely.

Comment: It is perfectly valid to post (and accept) an answer to your own question if you found the correct solution yourself and none of the exisiting answer already gave it. And it's much better than editing the original question.

Comment: @Wedvich: You do know that shaders/shader programs generate info log during their compilation, right (`glGetShaderInfoLog`/`glGetProgramInfoLog`)? Check return codes, when you compile shaders, and print compilation log if shader compilation fails. This way you'll be able to figure out what is the problem with ATI card. Ati cards are very strict when it comes to shader compilation, and nvidia cards are way too lax. NVidia allows many non-standard features (like 0.0f in shaders), but prints warning into shader/program log. As a result, you should definitely save shader/program log somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `frac(tex_offset)` to `fract(tex_offset)`, and it works fine on ATI cards, and also nVidia cards when #version is specified now.